# Making two overlapping boxes disappear into one another when clicked on

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I've been trying to create the following animation:

(1) I have a button consisting of a white 100x100 box on top of a black 100x100 box.

(2) Clicking on the button makes the white box disappear into the black box.
(see the result [here](https://codepen.io/danitrusca/pen/qywpEw))

```
// html
<div class="button">
  <div class="white u-on-top"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>

// css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  

 .white {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;    
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #000;

   position: absolute;    

   transition: .5s;    
  }
 .black {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: #000;
   border: 1px solid #000;
  }
}

.u-on-top {
  z-index: 1;
}
.u-at-bottom {
  z-index: -1;
}

// javascript
var btn = document.querySelector(".button");
var btnState = false;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var btnw = btn.querySelector(".white");
  if (!btnState) {
    btnw.style.transform = "scale(0)";
    btnState = true;
  } else {
    btnw.style.transform = "scale(1)";
    btnState = false;
  }
})
```

(3) What I've unsuccessfully been trying to do is to also make the black box disappear into the white box when clicked on.

So:

- clicking on the white box makes it disappear into the black box
- clicking on the black box makes it disappear into the white box
- clicking on the white box makes it disappear into the black box
- And so on...

My idea was to obtain the effect by modifying the z-index of the boxes when clicked on, using the utility classes u-on-top and u-at-bottom (eg the black box is brought to the top after the white box disappears), but I got some weird results.

Comment: Are you aware of the error in your CSS? As it's currently written the `.white` rules are nested within the rules for `.button`.

Comment: Err. confused, the example you link to does the white disappearing into black on the first click, then black disappearing into white on the second click. Doesn't that answer your question? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @David Thomas, I used SCSS nesting.

Comment: @barny, the white box becomes smaller and disappears into the black one. Clicking on the back box afterwards however does not make the black box smaller, but enlarge the white one back to its original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to adjust some transition, the trick is to add a delay to `z-index` so it changes after the scale effect. I have also change the JS code and reduced the CSS:

```js
var btnW = document.querySelector(".white");
var btnB = document.querySelector(".black");
var btnState = false;

btnW.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btnB.classList.remove('hide');
  btnW.classList.add('hide');
  btnW.classList.remove('u-on-top');
  btnB.classList.add('u-on-top');
})
btnB.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btnW.classList.remove('hide');
  btnB.classList.add('hide');
  btnB.classList.remove('u-on-top');
  btnW.classList.add('u-on-top');
})
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0s, z-index 0s 0.5s;
  z-index:0;
}

.button .white {
  background: #fff;
}

.button .black {
  background: #000;
}
.button>div.hide {
  transform:scale(0);
  transition: transform .5s, z-index 0s 0.5s;
}
.button>div.u-on-top {
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="white u-on-top"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're awesome. :)